# Facebook login with Torii and Simple-Auth : no authentication data returned

Tags: authentication, ember.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, ember-simple-auth

I tried to setup a facebook login using [Torii](http://vestorly.github.io/torii/) and [Simple-Auth Torii authenticator](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-torii). I am using ember-cli.

Here is my configuration :

```
// config/environment.js
ENV['torii'] = {
    providers: {
        'facebook-oauth2': {
            apiKey:      'my facebook app id'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my login code :

```
// app/controllers/login.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(LoginControllerMixin, {
  actions: {
    authenticateWithTorii: function(){
      this.get('session').authenticate(
        'simple-auth-authenticator:torii',
        'facebook-oauth2'
      ).then(
        function(data) {
          alert('SUCCESS ' + data);
        },
        function(error) {
          alert('There was an error when trying to sign you in: ' + error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

The popup is opening asking for authorization, then I see the alert with "SUCCESS UNDEFINED". I thought I will get some data I could use on my backend to definitely authentify the user (access token or facebook uid, etc...).

Did I miss something in the way to use Torii with Simple-Auth ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise returned by [`Session#authenticate`does not have a value](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-Session-authenticate) but everything that the torii authenticator resolves with is available via the session as soon as that's authenticated (which it is in your case as the returned promise has resolved). You could access e.g. a `token` property with

```
var _this = this;
this.get('session').authenticate(
  'simple-auth-authenticator:torii',
  'facebook-oauth2'
).then(function(data) {
  alert('SUCCESS ' + _this.get('session.token'));
})
```

You can also inspect the session's `content` property (which you shouldn't use otherwise as it's private but for debugging that's ok) to find out what's available:

```
console.log(this.get('session.content'))
```