# Ember cli simple auth login with facebook using torii authenticate against server using oauth2

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

How do i allow the user to login with facebook and take that facebook authentication code and pass it to my server using simple auth oauth2?

I obviously want to validate whether or not the user has permissions to make request to my server.

I have been looking all over and am not able to find anything that would point me in the right direction.

I see examples that tell me to do this
`this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:torii', 'facebook-oauth2');`
but what do i do with this afterwords? and how do i use this to check against my own server using oauth2?

A full example allowing multiple ways to login with server authentication that returns user info to be used later on in the application(user_id, firstname, lastname, etc...) would be most appreciated!!!

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25844756/1970061

Comment: I saw that and i was really hoping to be able to use things as is and not have to override or make my own connections. Cause in the future if the torii packages has a new version or make changes it wont reflect in what i did.

Comment: Currently there is no library which support your requirement, I had similar requirement in project and I used guidelines in mentioned answer.